# After startup i lost all icons, favorite bar and can open anything on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: icons, gnome-terminal, startup

After start-up, I got a grey screen, and lost all icons on the desktop and favorite bar. Also, I cannot see any settings or open anything, including the terminal and settings.
[image: picture of my screen]

I can open command with Alt+F2.

Anything I can do?

Comment: Anything you did that could have caused this? Something happened, a power outage for example? Can you log out from the menu? Does it persist after a reboot? With Alt+F2, you can issue `logout` to log out, and `reboot` to reboot the system. Add all relevant information to your actual question: use "edit"

Comment: Yeah well, first of all thank you for responding. This is my first post.

Comment: And yes, yesterday evening my PC crashing two times, like just froze, and I shut it down by holding down the power key. The first time I shut it down, it started fine, and the second time I started it up this morning and this happened. I was playing World of Warcraft through lutris when it crashed both times.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to open the terminal, so press Ctrl+Alt+T or Alt+F2 (Ctrl+Alt+T lets you see the output of commands better because it opens the actual terminal.)
Now you need to reinstall Yaru Icons, so type

```
sudo apt --reinstall install yaru-theme-icon
```

Now try to open a program such as files.
If the window top bar looks messed up, you might need to reinstall Yaru GTK3 theme so type

```
sudo apt --reinstall install yaru-theme-gtk
```

If there are no changes, you may need to reboot your machine.
Another solution would be to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 if you have to, because other stuff may have been corrupted.